# Calling toString method in Main function

Tags: java, object, tostring

I have 3 different classes. I have to get user input by using `BufferedReader` but by using `toString` method. Below is the codes in my `User2` (one of the classes).

How to call everything that user have input in the `toString`, at main function ? if i have to use object, how?

```
//in User2 class
@Override
public String toString() {
    try {
        //getting input using BufferedReader

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Enter customer name: ");
        this.name = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter customer address: ");
        this.address = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter customer contact no: ");
        this.hp = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "";
    }
return "" ;
}
```

I only know to print out everything in to string by using

```
 System.out.println(u2.toString());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reading from standard input in a `toString()` method is a really bad idea. And this isn't even a useful `toString()` method: it always returns `""`. Put this logic in a different method.

Comment: so any solution? @AndyTurner

Comment: " Put this logic in a different method".

Comment: toString should, ideally, produce a String that is representative of the Object. Reading from System really shouldn't be done.

Comment: "I have to get user input by using BufferedReader but by using toString method" Why do you *have to* do this? Is this homework - if so, I think you may have misinterpreted the instructions.

Comment: any idea on how to get rid of getting input at main function by using BufferedReader other than toString? @AndyTurner

Comment: Er... don't do it in the `toString()` method? As in, do it literally anywhere else.

Comment: any idea on how to get rid of getting input at main function by using BufferedReader other than toString?  @Zachary

Comment: @SyamilFuad Logistically it shouldn't be a problem using `toString()`. What we're saying is don't, as you will inevitable come into a problem down the line.

Comment: Please suggest another way/method to not to use toString @Zachary thank you. a line of code would help

Comment: Please suggest another way/method to not to use toString. thank you. a line of code would help @Zachary

Comment: Please suggest another way/method to not to use toString thank you. a line of code would help @AndyTurner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be defining an Object when you call it's `toString()` method, especially when you are using Scanner to read data from System.in. Rather, when you read data you should use the data to instantiate the Object. I haven't seen the layout of your classes, but I have a feeling you don't fully understand [what Objects are.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html)

The following Class defines a User; The user has a name, address and hp. You create a new User Object once you have this information as, in this situation, it doesn't make sense to have an Object that doesn't represent a known User.

The `toString()` method has been overriden such that it produces a String that is representative of what the Object describes - You should adjust this to how you want the Object to be representative when the Object to converted to a String. [Read more about the toString method and it's purpose.](https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method)

The `static User userFromInput()` method does what you want. As it is [static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), you may invoke it on the Class, meaning you don't have to instantiate an Object. This method takes input from the user (name, address and hp), instantiates a new User object and returns it.

```
 public class User {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String hp;

    public User (String name, String address, String hp) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.hp = hp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " : " + address + " : " + hp;
    }

    public static User userFromInput() {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

            System.out.print("Enter customer name: ");
            String name = br.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter customer address: ");
            String address = br.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter customer contact no: ");
            String hp = br.readLine();

            return new User(name, address, hp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hence, you should call for the user to input data and then print the Object to console using the following to lines:

```
User user1 = User.userFromInput();
System.out.println(user1.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you @zachary

Comment: @SyamilFuad Just ensure that that fulfills your specifications. Also make sure you close the BufferedReader, which I forgot to put there. The try-with-resource will handle this for you.